# Python: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType

Tags: python

I am learning to python and even though I have found resources on this error, their solution werent particularly clear when applied to my case.

Here it goes:

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 136, in <module>
    game()
  File "main.py", line 131, in game
    dealer_result = dealer()
  File "main.py", line 66, in dealer
    dvalue = value(dealer_hand)
  File "main.py", line 36, in value
    value += cards.get(c)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Context:

- it's a blackjack game.
- game() is a function that surrounds the whole game, with a whole subset of functions for each aspect.
- the error isnt consistent

Code Flow:
I have cards 2 to A with their values definited in a dictionary.

```
  cards = {
      "2": 2,
      "3": 3,
      "4": 4,
      "5": 5,
      "6": 6,
      "7": 7,
      "8": 8,
      "9": 9,
      "10": 10,
      "J": 10,
      "Q": 10,
      "K": 10,
      "A": 11,
  }
```

Game starts with a variable defining the player and dealer hands

`player_hand = start()`
and
`dealer_hand = start()`

where

```
  def start():
      hand = []
      hand.extend([random.choice(list(cards)), random.choice(list(cards))])
      return hand
```

at the start a global 'flag' variable is pre set to "h" to allow the code to enter a loop on the main part of the game

firstly we'll start by calculating the value of the player hand by using the `value(hand)` function:

```
  def value(hand):
      value = 0
      for c in hand:
          if c != "A":
              value += cards.get(c)
          elif c == "A" and value >= 11:
              value += 1
          else:
              value += 11
      return value
```

and attributing it to a p_value variable.

I assume this is where the error is, though, since the hand is a random choice of cards pulled from the dictionary, how could it not find such card when going through the same dictionary?

player phase:

```
def main(flag):
      p_value = value(player_hand)
      if p_value == 21:
          result = "blackjack"
      else:
          while flag == "h":
              if p_value == 21:
                  flag = "s"
              elif p_value > 21:
                  print("Bust")
                  flag = "s"
              if flag != "s":
                  flag = str(input("[h]it, [s]tay or [q]uit?: "))
              if flag == "h":
                  player_hand.extend(hit())
                  p_value = value(player_hand)
                  print("Player: Current value: " + str(p_value) + ". Current hand: " + ', '.join(player_hand))
              elif flag == "q":
                  exit()
      result = p_value
      return result
```

I then use the returned result to compare final player result vs. final dealer result

Dealer phase:

```
  def dealer():
      dvalue = value(dealer_hand)
      print("Dealer value: " + str(dvalue) + ". Dealer hand: " + ', '.join(dealer_hand))
      if dvalue == 21:
          result = "blackjack"
      else:
          while dvalue < 17:
              dealer_hand.extend(hit())
              dvalue = value(dealer_hand)
              print("Dealer value: " + str(dvalue) + ". Dealer hand: " + ', '.join(dealer_hand))
          result = dvalue
      return result
```

Real Scenario where the error occurred:

```
Play again? y/n: y
Player: Current value: 10. Current hand: 2, 8
Dealer: Current hand: ?, 5
[h]it, [s]tay or [q]uit?: s
Dealer value: 7. Dealer hand: 2, 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 136, in <module>
    game()
  File "main.py", line 131, in game
    dealer_result = dealer()
  File "main.py", line 66, in dealer
    dvalue = value(dealer_hand)
  File "main.py", line 36, in value
    value += cards.get(c)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Expected result is Dealer to keep looping through the hit() function until his hand value `value(dealer_hand)` is equal or greater to 17.

Comment: What is the value of `c` which gives you the error? See how to create a [mcve] and [edit] the question.

Comment: `cards.get(c)` is returning None, therefore `c` must be some value other than "2", "3", ... "A".  Print `c` and see what it is.

Comment: the `.get()` method of a dictionary provides a default value of `None` when a key cannot be found, or accepts a second arg for a custom default - if you always expect to find, consider indexing directly `my_dictionary[key]`, which will raise `KeyError` for missing keys and might give you more feedback

Comment: Despite it could have been a bit more minimal, this is a really well written first question. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`extend` takes an "iterable" and adds all the elements in that iterable to the list. A string is an iterable, and one of your values has more than one character.
`append`, on the other hand, takes a value and adds it as-is to the list.

To put it another way: `extend` is for adding zero or more elements from another collection of things; `append` is for adding exactly one element.

This example illustrates what the problem is:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.extend("10")
>>> a
['1', '0']
>>> b = []
>>> b.extend(["10"])
>>> b
['10']
>>> c = []
>>> c.append("10")
>>> c
['10']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt at psychic debugging:

What might be happening:

- `hit()` returns a string
- `..._hand.extend(hit())` then adds each character in the string to the hand
- If the card is `"10"`, it gets split into `"1"` and `"0"`, which are not in `cards`
- `cards.get(c)` returns `None` by default

What the solution would be: change `extend` to `append`; see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists or https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types.

Comment: This is very good psychic debugging, but really you should ask for clarification first. If your assumption is wrong, your answer is wrong. However, the fact `extend` doesn't fail, does give support to the idea `hit` returns something iterable.